# possible to access custom labels dynamically?

Tags: apex, customlabel

In apex you can reference a custom label with `system.Label.labelName`, but is there a more dynamic way to get a custom label for example `system.Label.get(labelName)`? I can't find anything like this in the documentation but was hoping it was possible.

I'm trying to have custom labels for fields to support multiple languages. The list of fields I'm showing is built in the controller and displayed inside an `apex:repeat` tag so I can't hardcode the labels. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're just looking for translating the field labels (as opposed to any other text on your visualforce pages), you'll want to use the translation workbench as fields are by nature multi-lingual already.

Comment: Standard fields are but what about custom fields?

Comment: Yep, all fields, including custom ones, can be translated using the translation workbench.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**EDIT**
This is now possible! You can instantiate a dynamic visualforce component in Apex to get this.

```
public String getLabel(String myLabel ){
    Component.Apex.OutputText output = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
    output.expressions.value = '{!$Label.'+ myLabel + '}';
    return String.valueOf(output.value);
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

No, you can't reference labels dynamically in apex. You can vote for this idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hhVGAAY). However, you can reference them dynamically from visualforce so you can put them on the page like so:

```
public class MyController
{
    public String mylabel{get; set;}

    public MyController()
    {
         mylabel='labelname';   
    }
}

<apex:page Controller="MyController">
    <apex:outputText> {!$Label[mylabel]} </apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know about the dynamic access in VF. Very cool. Must try soon! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like this is the best option currently available. I did find a more popular version of the idea that is asking a little bit more as well (retrieving translations): https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000714W

Comment: Very cool! Did not know that was possible.

Comment: This is super helpful !!

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, System throws System.VisualforceException: Visualforce Component types can only be created within a controller class for a Visualforce page.

Answer (score 20):

Following is a code snippet of a work-around. But it has a limitation of working Only in a constructor of a VF page controller class.

```
string labelName = 'DemoLabel';
Component.Apex.OutputText output;
output = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
output.expressions.value = '{!$Label.' + labelName + '}';
string labelValue = string.valueOf(output.value);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: got it working outside of a constructor
http://kevansfdc.blogspot.com/2017/02/retrieve-salesforce-label-dynamically.html

Comment: N.B. Referencing a labelName that does not exist results in an uncatchable Internal Server Error.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, System throws VisualforceException:
System.VisualforceException: Visualforce Component types can only be created within a controller class for a Visualforce page.

Comment: this is not working inside the class as I need to access the label value inside the same class dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There's another workaround by **KK Ramamoorthy** which will also work outside of constructors. Is has it's own limitation, though: it doesn't work in Trigger context because the getContent() is seen as a callout.

What is does is it renders an in-memory visualforce page that takes the label name as a url parameter (and optionally also a language parameter). Then it fetches the label text from the generated page.

https://kksfblog.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/lost-in-translation-an-api-for-dynamically-translating-custom-labels-in-apex/

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata API to get the labels and also translations as well.
Hope it will help out someone.

```
For labels : 
List<MetadataService.CustomLabel> csList = (List<MetadataService.CustomLabel>) service.readMetadata('CustomLabel', new String[] { 'a','b' }).getRecords();

For translations :
MetadataService.Translations translations = (MetadataService.Translations) service.readMetadata('Translations', new String[] { 'es' }).getRecords()[0];
```

[Add this apex-mdapi wrapper class to your org](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls)

Answer (score 0):

In summer 23 release notes, they introduced an easier method to [Access Labels in Apex Dynamically](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_system_label_methods.htm&release=244&type=5):

> Use the `System.Label.get(namespace, label, language)` method to get a custom label, optionally specifying a language.
>
> The feature now allows dynamic resolution of label names at run time, including overriding the user’s current language if a translation exists for the requested language. Previously, retrieving labels required compile-time knowledge of the label API name.

> You can also check if translation exists for a label and language in a namespace by using `Label.translationExists(namespace, label, language)`. You can’t access labels that are protected in a different namespace.

Need to wait until the release/feature is generally available.

Answer (score 0):

In Summer ’23 Release.
Use the System.Label.get(namespace, label, language) method to get a custom label, optionally specifying a language. The feature now allows dynamic resolution of label names at run time, including overriding the user’s current language if a translation exists for the requested language. Previously, retrieving labels required compile-time knowledge of the label API name.

```
String strLabel = System.Label.get('namespace','LableName','hi')
```